# Why atan2(y,x) is faster to compute than arcsin or arccos?

Tags: performance, trigonometry

I've read that when I know Y and X it's better to compute `atan2(y,x)` to get the angle instead of using a single value with asin and acos. I've tried to dig into `math.h` lib but I didn't found any formula.

Can someone explain why `atan2` is better?

Comment: Well, there are obvious reasons why `atan2` is *better*: you don't need to compute a quotient first, you don't have any problems with one variable being zero or nearly so, you don't have to adjust the output to get in the right semicircle....

Comment: BTW it's usually good to post code when you ask a question. This way people don't have to guess, and will provide a better answer. Also, it's good to add a tag for the language of your code. This will let experts in that language find your question easier. You can [edit] your question to include the code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are comparing two pieces of code that look mostly like this:

```
angle = atan2(x, y);
```

and

```
angle = acos(x / sqrt(x * x + y * y));
```

(I assume C code)

The first part calculates what you need directly, while the second part does it in a roundabout way - it's natural to expect that the first one is faster (**unless** `atan2` implementation contains some variant of the second code example).

In addition, `atan` is a pretty "primitive" function - it "feels" more general than "acos" or "asin". [x87 has a command for it](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_106.html), so I expect old implementations of `acos` to use `atan2` internally. Also, I don't know enough of SSE, but it would be reasonable to expect SSE to implement `atan2`, even just for compatibility with x87.

Answer (score 1):

```
theta = atan2(y,x);
```

is more simple than:

```
float in = 1.0/sqrt(x*x+y*y);
theta = acos(x*in);
if(y<0)
    theta = -acos(x*in);
else
    theta = acos(y*in);
```

Don't you think? It's simpler, and maybe faster, depending on the implementation.

Now, if x and y are not arbitrary, but if you can assume for instance that x²+y²=1 and y>=0, then

```
theta = acos(x);
```

Is more simple, and maybe faster than atan2. But again, speed with vary with implementations. The atan2 might, or might not, be implemented with acos and asin, or using faster algorithms.